# Build executable war/jar for Maven based dynamic project that has restful Services and Swing features

Tags: java, swing, maven, tomcat, pom.xml

I need to make an Executable War/Jar of a Dynamic web based application.
our goal is to :

- Novice users can quickly deploy in one click manner with no prerequisites to be installed on deployment Environment i.e  he/she must not be setting class paths variables, java_home, standalone Tomcat installation etc, Every time WEB APP folder delete and deploy new .war in Tomcat etc .
- minimize the deployment time
- in case of the App version update (obviously Major update in functionality) we will deliver the whole package which will be just one complete executable for deployment.
  I found couple of links for this , I was able to make a stanalone jar, but that did't work as per the normal app deployment.
  -http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/executable-war-jar.html
  -http://java-creed-examples.googlecode.com/svn/maven/How%20To%20Run%20Embedded%20Tomcat%20with%20Maven/

Please can somebody help me create a sample Hello work project that meets the above requirement.

I will really be grateful for the quick support.

Answer (score 0):

"executable war", although it may sound appealing to you, is a **horrendous** idea:

- i assume when you say "web application" you mean something servlet/jax-rs based
- which means that in order to be a stand-alone "executable" you must package various servlet/jax-rs/someSpec libraries/implementations (maybe an embedded jetty)
- those dependency classes will stick around and "interfere" with the container-provided classes that should be used when you deploy the exact same war on, say, tomcat (you will have 2 different implementations of class `Servlet` on the path)
- this sort of class aliasing issue is relatively hard to spot and identify, and if you're especially unlucky simple hello world examples will work while more complicated ones with fail in weird ways.

my suggestion to you is split your code up into 3 (maven?) modules (im assuming a jax-rs app):

1. api-impl, containing just `@Resource` classes, which has a "provided" dependency on all specs
2. a war module, which packages up #1 above in a war file fit for deployment on a container (say tomcat)
3. an executable fat jar module that packages up #1 along with actual implementations (say jetty and jersey) and has a `main()` method that boots an embedded jetty, along with a *.bat/*.sh script with something like `java -jar fat.jar` to run it. look into the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for this.

your users can choose between the fat jar (for beginners) and the war (for advanced users)